# Running multiple processes and coordinating completion

Tags: python, parallel-processing, popen

I am a little confused about the way Popen works and I am hoping this is something silly. I am never getting a completion, and poll seems to be returning something odd (log attached)

This is backing up a triplet of schemas (Tablespace) using a utility (CSSBACKUP)  supplied to do this.

```
for i in range(len(schematype)):
    schema_base = schemaname + '_' + schematype[i]  # we need this without the trailing space.
    outputstring = base_folder + '\\' + schemaname + '\\' + schema_base + '_' + timestr + '_cssbackup '
    rc = os.unlink(outputstring)   # wont run if there is a backup already
    logstring = base_folder + '\\' + schemaname + '\\' + schema_base + '_' + timestr + '.log'
    exString = "cssbackup " + phys_string + '-schema '+ schema_base + ' ' + '-file ' + outputstring + '-log '+ logstring
    logging.debug(exString)
    processlist.append(subprocess.Popen(exString)) # start a seperate thread for each one, but we don't want to proceed until processlist[].poll == None (thread is complete)
    procdone[i] = False
```

Now that I have all the processes spawn, I need to sync them up

```
while finishit < len(schematype):
    time.sleep(CSTU_CFG.get(hostname).get("logintv"))                                   # need a delay to keep this program from thrashing
    for i in range(len(schematype)):                            # check each of the procs
        if procdone[i] is not True:                                 # if it completed, skip it 
           if processlist[i].poll is not None:                  # if it returns something other than "none" it's still running
                logging.debug('   Running '+ schematype[i] + ' ' + str(processlist[i])+ ' '+ str(time.time() - start_time))
                procdone[i] = False
           else:
                procdone[i] = True                              # None was returned so it's finished
                logging.debug('   Ended '+ schematype[i])           # log it 
                finishit = finishit + 1                         # update the count
                processlist[i].kill                             # kill the process that was running ( Saves memory )

logging.debug('Dump functions complete')
```

When I run this, I don't get what  I am expecting. I was expecting a pid in the return but I dont see it. So what I get back isnt useful for the .poll command.

So the program runs forever even after the shell that it spawned are gone.

I'm missing something basic.

THanks

11:26:26,133 root, DEBUG    Running local  30.014784812927246
11:26:26,133 root, DEBUG    Running central  30.014784812927246
11:26:26,133 root, DEBUG    Running mngt  30.014784812927246
11:26:56,148 root, DEBUG    Running local  60.02956962585449
11:26:56,148 root, DEBUG    Running central  60.02956962585449
11:26:56,148 root, DEBUG    Running mngt  60.02956962585449
11:27:26,162 root, DEBUG    Running local  90.04435467720032
11:27:26,162 root, DEBUG    Running central  90.04435467720032
11:27:26,162 root, DEBUG    Running mngt  90.04435467720032
11:27:56,177 root, DEBUG    Running local  120.05913925170898
11:27:56,177 root, DEBUG    Running central  120.05913925170898
11:27:56,177 root, DEBUG    Running mngt  120.05913925170898
11:28:26,192 root, DEBUG    Running local  150.07392406463623

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should *call* poll. `if processlist[i].poll is not None` will always evaluate to True, because `processlist[i].poll` is the function object, not the result of `processlist[i].poll()`.

**Edit:**
This looks an quite complicated way to do something like

```
p = multiprocessing.Pool(n)
p.map_async(subprocess.call, commands)
```

As a suggestion, you may want to check the multiprocessing module.

Comment: That was a head slapping moment but now a new problem shows up. When I ran it, the processes kept running but the process checker continued. So i added a .poll() right after the creation and they seem to be created with None. So this gets me closer, but not there. So perhaps my problem is in the popen(exString) ?

Comment: There are multiple details here. For example, `subprocess.Popen` requires either a list of arguments or a `shell=True` argument. `poll()` returns None when running and the returncode when finished, so the check is inverted. I also don't think you need to kill the process after it finishes. In general, it would be easier to debug if you had an example which is a little more minimal and complete https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve .

Comment: I honestly thought it was the other way around but eliminating the inverted check worked flawlessly. I'll get rid of the kill. Thank you